# MySQL using 3 tables and relations - How do I get all information from one side and names from the other?

Tags: mysql, join

Using: PHP 8

I have three tables. The first two have a relationship and the second two have a relationship.
I need data from all three, but some information might not be available in the second table. Also, I need to separate the data from the second table when multiple matches are found in the relation. Is this possible with sql, or should I be thinking in terms of multiple queries and combining them with PHP?

I need All people to be displayed and related certifications' expiration dates.

**People**

| id | Name | DoB | requires_cert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person 1 | 2000-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | Person 2 | 2006-06-06 | 0 |
| 3 | Person 3 | 1980-01-01 | 1 |

**Certifications**

| person_id | certification_id | Expiration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2025-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2066-06-06 |
| 1 | 2 | 2024-03-30 |

**Certification Types**

| id | certification_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Certification 1 |
| 2 | Certification 2 |

I've tried so many combinations of joins and unions, and can't figure this out for the life of me.

My desired output would be to display the following table:

| id | Name | DoB | Certification 1 | Certification 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person 1 | 2000-01-01 | 2025-01-01 | 2024-03-30 |
| 2 | Person 2 | 2006-06-06 | n/a | n/a |
| 3 | Person 3 | 1980-01-01 | n/a | 2066-06-06 |

Comment: Wouldn't `select * from persons as p left join certs as c on c.person_id = p.id left join cert_types as ct on ct.id = c.certification_id` do it? Could `group_concat` the `certification_name` and `Expiration` then split on delimiter and output more cells in your display as needed.. Is total number of certs known?

Comment: @user3783243 thank you! No, the total number of certs will grow over time, as the expired certificates would just need to be filtered out for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot the data but MySQL does not have a pivot function, so we emulate the functionality with conditional aggregation.  You would start by getting the list of cert_types that you are interested in and then using that to dynamically build a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT p.*,
  MAX(IF(c.certification_id = 1, c.expiration, NULL)) AS 'Certificate 1',
  MAX(IF(c.certification_id = 2, c.expiration, NULL)) AS 'Certificate 2'  
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN certs c ON p.id = c.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Output:

| id | name | dob | requires_cert | Certificate 1 | Certificate 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person 1 | 2000-01-01 | 1 | 2025-01-01 | 2024-03-30 |
| 2 | Person 2 | 2006-06-06 | 0 | null | null |
| 3 | Person 3 | 1980-01-01 | 1 | null | 2066-06-06 |

Alternatively, as suggested by [user3783243 in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203768/mysql-using-3-tables-and-relations-how-do-i-get-all-information-from-one-side#comment137871092_78203768), you could just [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) the certs:

```sql
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ct.name, ':', c.expiration) AS certificates
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN certs c ON p.id = c.person_id
LEFT JOIN cert_types ct ON c.certification_id = ct.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Output:

| id | name | dob | requires_cert | certificates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person 1 | 2000-01-01 | 1 | Certification 1:2025-01-01,Certification 2:2024-03-30 |
| 2 | Person 2 | 2006-06-06 | 0 | null |
| 3 | Person 3 | 1980-01-01 | 1 | Certification 2:2066-06-06 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g_JIthML).

Comment: But the SELECT clause has columns which are not defined in the GROUP BY clause. This is incompatible with MySQL 8's default `sql_mode` which has `only_full_group_by`, so an error will be thrown in.

Comment: This is the error I got when running the query under workbench: Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testdb.p.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @blabla_bingo You seem to be misunderstanding how [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) works. All columns in `people` are functionally dependent on `p.id`, as it is the PK. The other expressions in both queries are aggregates.

Comment: @blabla_bingo Note that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled for the fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/o187Tmz0

Comment: @user1191247 Both of these work for my purpose. Thank you!

Comment: @user1191247, hi, I found the cause of error. PK has to be defined for id to make it functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. When I was testing my own solution(which is all but identical to the one provided by Sandun LB), I didn't add PK for id as the OP did not specifically say it's. Therefore,it is possible an ID is NOT a PK . For instance, the table provided could be partial as additional columns have been removed to simplify the question.

Comment: @blabla_bingo, In this case, if the table has a column called `languages` which stores one language for a row instead of resorting to comma-separated value, it will have duplicate id when a person has multiple languages.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I grant you that OP does not include the DDL, but It is not an unreasonable assumption that an integer column called `id` would be the PK. Given that there can be multiple rows for each `(person_id, certification_id)`, you would still need to use GROUP BY and MAX to get the latest expiry date for each pair, not too mention the unnecessary _cartesian explosion_ potential in the joins - https://dbfiddle.uk/Fi47YlB2